# Bug in reading and writing cookies with ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

There are 2 links on a webpage. HOME AND LOGIN.
My user tells me that HOME used to bring her directly to a page in the application.
The behavior for HOME is now the same as LOGIN.

I looked in the code and discovered that it is using some kind of cookie management to achieve this.

Here is a snippet of code that saves a cookie to the browser, if a checkbox on the page is checked.

```
                if (remember != "")
                {
                    HttpCookie cookieRememberMe = new HttpCookie("RememberMe") {Value = remember};
                    this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieRememberMe);
                    HttpCookie cookieCustomerId = new HttpCookie("CustomerId") {Value = ViewBag.CustomerId.ToString()};
                    this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieCustomerId);
                    if (Response != null)
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["CustomerId"].Value = cookieCustomerId.Value;
                        Response.Cookies["CustomerId"].Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
                        Response.Cookies["RememberMe"].Value = cookieRememberMe.Value;
                        Response.Cookies["RememberMe"].Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
                    }
                }
```

When the user clicks on the homepage, it is supposed to navigate that user away from the login screen, but that has stopped working. Here is the code when the user clicks on HOME.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Session["LoggedIn"] = false;
            Session["CustomerId"] = 0;
            if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("CustomerId") && Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("RememberMe"))
            {
                if (Request.Cookies["CustomerId"].Expires >= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    var cid = Request.Cookies["CustomerId"].Value;

                    var u = Request.Cookies["RememberMe"].Value;
                    if (u != "")
                    {
                        Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
                        Session["CustomerId"] = cid;
                        return RedirectToAction("PaymentHistory", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();

        }
```

Debugging the code leads me to believe that the cookies are getting stored, but the expiry date of the cookie is not being honored. The code should have never worked in that case, but she says that the code worked all the time and has now stopped working.

Comment: This leads me to believe it has more to do with the User's browser settings than the code. She may have disabled cookies or set her browser to clear these on exit. Have you debugged through the user's browser and checked the user's browser settings?

Comment: This is great. So if I want to impersonate any other customer, all I have to do is modify the CustomerId cookie. Free stuff! What's your website so I can go steal everyone's identity and get rich?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the check on Expires is not needed since the cookie will not exists if it's expired.

Comment: @RyanWilson I will have to check her browser settings. I haven't done that.

Comment: @abhi That would be where I'd start looking.

Comment: @mason Good point!

Comment: @the_lotus Expires is the only way to delete the cookie. So I believe it is needed. When the user clicks on logout, the expires is set to day -1.